# How can I insert a list of names from one list into the 2nd line, then increasing by 3 lines there after in Notepad++?

Tags: command-line, notepad++

I have a list of servers:

```
v29a3xx01
v29a3xx02
v29a3xx03
```

And I'm trying to insert it into some easy commands, a template that I made:

```
no
(currently blank line)
1
no
(currently blank line)
1
no
(currently blank line)
1
```

So the final output would be:

```
no
v29a3xx01
1
no
v29a3xx02
1
no
v29a3xx03
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this result by using regular expression.

- Open the Replace menu in notepad++ (CTRL+H)
- Put this RegEx in the search field (all your servers name must start with "v29") : `^(v29.*)$`
- Put this replace pattern in Replace field : `no\r\n$1\r\n1`
- Click on Replace all

You can change the Replace pattern if you want to change the commands.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! I was able to use it  for all the diff server type names.

Comment: @TJones - please mark the answer as answered if you found it helpful.